# Securing AJAX API

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, api

I have an API (1) on which I have build an web application with its own AJAX API (2). The reason for this is not to expose the source API. 
However, the web application uses AJAX (through JQuery) go get new data from its AJAX API, the data retrieved is currently in XML.
Lately I have secured the main API (1) with an authorization algorithm. However, I would like to secure the web application as well so it cannot be parsed. Currently it is being parsed to get the hash used to call the AJAX API, which returns XML.

My question: How can I improve the security and decrease the possibility of others able to parse my web application.
The only ideas I have are: stop sending XML, but send HTML instead. Use flash (yet, this is not an option).

I understand that since the site is public, and no login can be implemented, it can be hard to refuse access to bots (non legitimate users). Also, Flash is not an option... it never is ;)

*edit*
The Web Application I am referring to: https://bikemap.appified.net/

Comment: "I would like to secure the web application as well so it cannot be parsed" --- it's not possible. If browser can show something - it can be parsed in the very similar way how browser works

Comment: Another mention: AJAX API has nothing different from generic page, and should be secured in absolutely the same way

Comment: I know all that. First one, writing "I have an API and an API..." just makes the reading confusing. Second, I wrote: "I understand that since the site is public, and no login can be implemented, it can be hard to refuse access to bots", so yes, I understand both your points.

Comment: Please, do read the question again. I wrote: "How can I improve the security and decrease the possibility of others able to parse my web application.".

Comment: ... in other words: How can I make security better, and how can I make it harder to parse... I am sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: better than **what**? We don't know what you currently have. Btw, the 100% way to prevent any scraping is to turn off the server

Comment: Very funny. Ok, fair enough: https://bikemap.appified.net/

Comment: as long as you don't have authentication - it's pretty trivial to parse all the data in a way you wouldn't detect ever. Just pass all the headers the valid client does and perform queries with reasonable interval, like it is a human actions. PS: out of curiosity - is that data *that important* for anyone else?

Comment: Just keep in mind that "decrease the possibility of others able to parse my web application" is not security in any meaningful way. If an attacker wants to access your AJAX API in ways you don't want, they will not be deterred just by the mere inconvenience of some obfuscation, and if they're not that determined you should not consider them a threat at all.

Comment: Thank you @lanzz, finaly a valid comment. From past experience, I have found out that if it is harder to read, it doesn't get parsed as easily. Hence the reason I would like to make reading it harder.
However, I understand that my question is to unclear to get a clear answer on it.

Comment: Your question is clear enough, but I doubt you will receive an answer that you're going to like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat of an odd request; you wish to lock down a system that your own web application depends on to work. This is almost always a recipe for disaster.

Web applications should always expect to be sidelined, so the real security must come from the server; tarpitting, session tokens, throttling, etc.

If that's already in place, I don't see any reason why should jump through hoops in your own web application to give robots a tougher time ... unless you really want to separate humans from robots ;-)

One way to reduce the refactoring pain on your side is to wrap the `$.ajax` function in a piece of code that could sign the outgoing requests (or somehow add fields to it) ... then minify / obscurify that code and hope it won't get decoded so fast.

Comment: I have that, and that is already in place. The main API is used for the iOS and Android application. The web application makes it own layer on top of that.

Comment: @PaulPeelen Then why not also add authorization in the web application?

Comment: Because the users are normal every-day consumers. This is not a private service, just private from robots, and legal notices don't help.

Comment: @PaulPeelen Aha, so we're embarking on the "reasonable doubt" robot detection :)

Comment: @PaulPeelen updated my answer with how I would tackle it, but it remains difficult ... there are quite a few metrics to consider =/

Comment: Thnx. I'll have a look at it and see if I can use it. Thnx!